# CodeIgniter Design Of Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a user model that has properties such as username, password, first name, last name, address...etc

What is the best way to have these properties set on the model so I can insert or update into the database?

Should I have add, update..ect methods that take a whole list of parameters or just an array.

My questions is: How would you write a simple User model with the above fields in CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using [CodeIgniter's models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) which I find rather anoying. CodeIgniter will just provide a Db object and you'll probably end up doing queries into the database.

I use another way, with CI project I use [Propel](http://propelorm.org), which is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping) (basically what you want to do) and it's relatively easy to integrate, you can get an [integration guide](http://davidcondemarin.blogspot.com/2011/01/using-propel-with-codeigniter.html) I wrote here.

Hope I can help!

Comment: Sounds like Propel will be awesome

Comment: Propel is indeed awsome, and has some cool features, you should definately check it out...